# Caption left on centered figure doesn't work

Tags: luatex, captions

I searched for this topic in several threads but didn't succeed. My MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,naustrian]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm, showframe]{geometry} % for margins on a A4paper
\usepackage[Export]{adjustbox} 
\usepackage{caption} % config is done for table and image separately
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=unnumbered, name=Quelle, font=small, singlelinecheck=false}
\begin{document}
Mit einer Grafik

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
    \rule{5cm}{5cm}
    \caption{ Grafik3 }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I would like to have the caption not centered under the image but starting on the left side of the image.

To my understanding the `singlelinecheck=false` should align the caption to the left in the center. But somehow this doesn't work.

After some discussion I'm not really sure if this is even possible.

Using `luatex 1.13.2`, caption `2020/09/21`

**Update:** Simplified sample; changed image; rewording my aim

Comment: Note that `\begin{center}begin{figure}` makes no sense. Any centering information goes inside the `figure` env (and you should use `\centering` not the `center` env.

Comment: Please note that your example is not self contained as we do not have access to `images/c4098039054573c426accba79be0cc38ce32d517.tex`

Comment: Is the image it self even relevant? I'd use `\rule{5cm}{5cm}` instead

Comment: Now I don't really understand your question. What does ` align the caption to the left in the center`. Perhaps you should start by stating what your end goal is.

Comment: Well the caption should be starting on the left side of the image and NOT at the left side of the page. I thought the title of the content is clear enough - obviously not :-/

Comment: No that is definitely not clear. The caption it self does not really know about the size of the image, so you probably need other tools

Comment: Just for the sake of completness: another update - I'll delete some of my other comments which refer just to the updates.

Comment: you might get away (untested) by using the `varwidth` package and wrap the `varwidth` env around the image _and_ caption. The `varwidth` env needs an argument in `{}`'s, a length to start from, you can use `\textwidth` or `\linewidth`

Comment: The proposed solution with `varwidth` would work if I knew the size in advance. For the simple `\rule`  I have it but with an image of unknown size not really an approach. Anyway thx for your help.

Comment: Not needed because varwidth adjusts  it self to the size inside the box, and since you probably never have any images wider than `\linewidth` it is a good starting point for `varwidth`. This is the whole point of `varwidth` otherwise we'd used `minipage`

Comment: Hmm, but I can see that it complains: `Package varwidth Warning: Failed to reprocess entire contents on input line 17.` Presumably because of how `\caption` works. I have no more suggestions.